# Высота строк в таблице word с объединенными ячейками

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, com, visual-studio-2010, office-interop

Подскажите пожалуйста как кодом (Visual Studio 2010 .NET Framework 4) сделать высоту всех строк с текстом "Итого:" равной 0,7 см.

Фото с примером таблицы прилагаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код ниже работает неправильно — сбивает высоту объединенных ячеек в первом столбце.

```
wdApp.Selection.Tables(1).Select()
With wdApp.Selection.Find
    .Text = "Итого:"
    Do While .Execute = True
        wdApp.Selection.Rows.HeightRule = WdRowHeightRule.wdRowHeightExactly
        wdApp.Selection.Rows.Height = wdApp.CentimetersToPoints(0.7)
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: Судя по скриншоту, нужно менять и высоту предыдущей строки... и это нужно сделать явно.

Comment: Можете кодом подсказать как определить высоту текущую (для строки с "итого"), затем уменьшить ее до 0.7, а к предыдущей добавить разницу?